# MongoDB Replica Sets and HA

Tags: mongodb, high-availability

I've created a two member MongoDB replica set.
According to rs.status(), both members are successfully connected.

Member A uses port 27018.
Member B uses port 27019.

If member A goes down, I want my client to automatically fail over to Member B.
How do I get the client to do this?
How does it know that it needs to switch to port 27019?

Comment: Please read the [MongoDB docs about replication](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/replication/). Your questions are answered there => tl;dr : Failover happens automatically in case you configured everything according to the docs, 2 member replica sets are evil, running mongodb on non-standard ports makes administration harder than necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You won't be able to do that with only 2 members in your Replica Set.

When the Primary goes down (I assume in your exemple that member A is the Primary), the other members must elect a new Primary. To become the new Primary, a member must receive the majority of the votes, meaning more than 50%. If you have only 2 members and one goes down only one member remains, that means it is impossible to get the majority of the votes (2).

What you want to do is either add another Secondary member, so if your Primary goes down the other two will be able to elect a new Primary between them two. Or you can add an Arbiter, which is a light `mongod` process (potentially sharing another server) and whose function is just to participate to the election.

Anyway, I think that when the new Primary is elected, the switch is supposed to be transparent if you built your application properly: when you instantiate your driver, you pass it a list of servers and the name of the Replica Set they are running on, so if one fails it will switch to the second one. But I may be wrong on that point...

More information on this: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-high-availability/